# Как убрать из URL название любого из контролеров в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, .htaccess, url-manager

есть такой urlManager

```
 'urlManager' => [
 'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
 'showScriptName' => false,
 'rules' => [
      '' => 'site/index',
      '<action:\w+>' => 'site/<action>',
 ],
```

в корне проекта www есть такой .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ web/index.php
</IfModule>
```

а в папке web такой

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

так же имеются два контроллера с site и auth, в бушующем их будет больше. как для них всех сделать вид URL-ов такого типа mysite.ru/(тут любой из action-ов)?

Comment: Сделай все экшены в одном контроллере. Мгновенно поймешь, что это не самый хороший вариант и откажешься от этой глупой затеи.

Comment: Что произойдет если в контроллерах будут одинаковые экшены(site/index и test/index)?

Comment: @edvardpotter либо их исключить либо будет ошибка

Comment: Вас, уже не наводит это на мысль что вы идете не ту сторону?

Comment: @edvardpotter направьте меня в нужное русло? =)

Comment: Тут вопрос заключается в другом, зачем такое вообще нужно делать? Либо пишите все одном контроллере(тогда исключается вариант с одинаковыми экшенами) или как вариант можете сделать правило с регуляркой и адреса у вас будут примерно такие: `controller_action`, т.е. - `site_index`,'test_update'.

Comment: @edvardpotter ок, спасибо, буду думать в сторону одного контроллера

Comment: Но вообще советовал бы написать менеджер, в котором регистрировать экшены(с проверкой на уникальность), тогда у вас код будет разбит на контроллеры как вы хотите(что в принципе правильно), и дублирования не будет

Comment: @edvardpotter это надо создать отдельный контроллер в котором будут проверятся все контроллеры с их экшенами?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте настроить urlManager так:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            [
                'pattern' => '',
                'route' => 'site/index',
            ],
            [
                'pattern' => '<action>/<id:\w+>',
                'route' => '<controller>/<action>',
                'suffix' => ''
            ],
            [
                'pattern' => '<action>',
                'route' => '<controller>/<action>',
                'suffix' => ''
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: спасибо, но к сожалению это не сработало.